# jQuery .on not quite working to detect clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess I am not doing this right. Why doesn't the .on function work here?

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-test="test">TEST BUTTON</button>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close" data-test="test">TEST LINK</button>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").on('test', '[data-test="test"]', function() { alert("got test!!!"); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and there's no `test` event.

Comment: I think you forgot how to JavaScript... There isn't a `test` event. And also there is no `<document>` tag in HTML.

Comment: change your html structure as in my answer bellow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document` is a object not a string, 
change `$("document")` to `$(document)`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DUn5f/

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-test="test"]', function() { 
    alert("got test!!!");
});
```

Comment: Nope, neither $(document) nor $(window) has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

As this is button is no being added dynamically the easiest solution would be

```
$(".close").click (function() { alert("got test!!!"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '[data-test="test"]', function() { alert("got test!!!"); });

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uSQg6/

change your html structure to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(document).on('click', '[data-test="test"]', function() { alert("got test!!!"); });

     });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-test="test">TEST BUTTON</button>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close" data-test="test">TEST LINK</button>

  </body>
</html>
```